# Country autocomplete textfield in JSF2 (Primefaces Component Lib) implementation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, country

What is the best way to implement a country autocomplete textfield in JSF2?

I would like to know if there are better ways than implementing a bean to inject a list of countries either from the database or an XML data source.

I am using the primefaces component library, would there be a ready-made plugin i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a managed bean anyway. Otherwise you can't reference it in JSF views. If the data is not subject to changes, just load and initialize it once in an application scoped bean. If the data needs to be refreshed on, for example, daily basis, make use of a `@Singleton` EJB with `@Schedule` and let your managed bean delegate to it.

PrimeFaces has a [`<p:autoComplete>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf). You can find an example on their showcase. You can let the `completeMethod` point to the application scoped bean and point the `value` to the request/view scoped form bean.

Comment: Thanks for the practical insights.